# RHEL/Rocky 8.8 - 100% CPU and Memory lockup on "make"

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, grub2, compiling, make

Our software product runs correctly on all RHEL 8 versions, until we updated to RHEL 8.8.  While running a "make" on Version 8.8, it failed because the RHEL skb_recv_datagram() was updated to take three parameters instead of four.  That's not a problem we haven't seen before, so we updated our file to call the function with 3 parameters.  After that change, our make now triggers 100% CPU and Memory usage, hanging the host.

We have been trying to troubleshoot the issue, without success.  The host hang leaves no crash or panic file to analyze, and zero’s out log files being captured during the hang.  We have only been able to capture terminal output leading up to the hang.  The problem is clearly during the “make” that compiles our kernel drivers on the host.  Processes “cc1” and “depmod” showed 100% CPU before the host totally hung.

Trying to isolate the problem, we removed the skb_recv_datagram() function totally from the file and then compiled and mounted our software as usual.  The problem still happens.  We believe this proves that other than the skb_recv_datagram function, there were other changes introduced in RHEL 8.8 that affected the installation of our streams modules and cause the 100% spinout of the host.  Furthermore, after several tests our RHEL 8.8 OS got corrupted and the host can only be booted in Emergency Mode!

This problem occurs 100% of the time, and now that my host is in read-only mode.  I have reached out to Redhat for support, but I wanted to check with the amazing community here, where I have lurked for years.

Has anyone seen a problem like this on RHEL 8.8?  Are there any new default BOOT options in RHEL 8.8?  In the past, RHEL has introduced ones that impacted our software (for instance, kaslr and hardened_usercopy).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.